# Is it possible to run 3.5 ASP.NET web form and MVC 3.0 on same project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a .net 3.5 webform corporate website and are in the process of upgrading to MVC 4.0. Since this is the large scale website, we want to upgrade bit by bit.

Could anyone please suggest whether it is possible to achieve above i.e running both ASP.NET WEbForm and MVC in one web project? Or is there much better way to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You should read two blog posts by Scott Hanselman regarding the subject: - [Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) - [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) He has also created a [AddMvc3ToWebForms](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms) NuGet package to support the scenario (you can read li

Answer (score 2):

Did you check this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) by Scott Hanselman? Since you are talking of .net 3.5 web forms and MVC 4.0 possibly you will need to set the application pool run-time to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any practical experience to share but I've read (or been told) that it's possible. The example used was a case like yours i.e. having a large codebase and wanting to do a gradual migration to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run MVC and Webforms side by side in the same project.